# Gridcontrol Sum Value

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

I use a button on click event to add a product to my GridControl. On the event, theres a for-loop that calculates the items. My problem is when clicking the event, it adds the product to the grid, but it does not calculate the item.

I use a void method to calculate and call it with gridrowcount changed event, however, I don't want this. I want it to calculate when adding a product.

```
void Hesapla()
{
    decimal Toplam = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount + 1; i++)
    {
        Toplam += decimal.Parse(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Tpl").ToString());

    }
    txtToplam.Text = Toplam.ToString("0.00");
    btnAdetText.Text = gridView1.RowCount.ToString() + " Ürün";
}
```

When I change `RowCount` to -1 or +1 it gives an error.

My code for adding a product:

```
SimpleButton urun = (SimpleButton)sender;
UrunID = Convert.ToInt16(urun.Tag);
DataRow Dr = cls.urunSec(UrunID);
Ses2();
gridView1.AddNewRow();

gridView1.SetRowCellValue(DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, "ID", Dr["ID"].ToString());
gridView1.SetRowCellValue(DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, "STOKADI", Dr["STOKADI"].ToString());
gridView1.SetRowCellValue(DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, "ADET", Adet);
gridView1.SetRowCellValue(DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, "TOPLAM", Dr["SATISFIYAT"].ToString());
```

Comment: Why not just call `Hesapla();` after you have added a new row? Also make sure `gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Tpl")` is actually returning something. I cant really see if `Tpl` is a field value in the code provided.

Comment: Tpl is Unbound column name. And use ADET*TOPLAM column.

Comment: when added 2 ıtems is calculate ı want when add one product calculate word

Comment: thanks for reply regards

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? 

One thing though, `rowHandle` parameter in `GetRowCellValue()` is a zero based index, meaning it starts at 0. RowCount represents the number of visible rows in the grid. Lets say there 5 rows, your row handle can only go from `0..4`, because it starts at zero. So in your for-loop, you are going from `0..RowCount`. You should be using this in your for loop `for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)` since the less-than sign will limit it to `0..RowCount - 1`.

Comment: I've tried it . But the error continues. After you add a product , click anywhere if I calculated. But the first product added is not calculated

Comment: when use -1  error with gridView1.AddNewRow(); method.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Null referance error

Comment: 2 days I'm dealing with it. Can you make a remote connection ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/tLO9_t54c-c here ı upload video for this

Comment: Thanks I can see the problem now. Your method `Hesapla()` works fine now after you have updated it. The event `gridView1_RowCountChanged` fires `Hesapla()`, which is what happens when you click add/remove. However, when you click one of the items on the big grid (on the left), you should also call `Hesapla()` so that the text boxes update.

Comment: I cant see the event name, for instance when clicking for instance on "VILEDA TEMIZLIK...", but you need to add `Hesapla();` at the end of that event call.

Comment: You see first ıtem when adding not calculate ı want this

Comment: when ı add a new product . product price writing in textbox

Comment: VILEDA TEMIZLIK. is product name

Answer (score 0):

```html
 private void urn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Hi 
            // ım add new product from here
            SimpleButton urun = (SimpleButton)sender;
            UrunID = Convert.ToInt16(urun.Tag);
            DataRow Dr = cls.urunSec(UrunID);
            Ses2();
            gridView1.AddNewRow();
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, "ID", Dr["ID"].ToString());
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, "STOKADI", Dr["STOKADI"].ToString());
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, "MIKTAR", Adet);
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, "BIRIMFIYAT", Dr["SATISFIYAT"].ToString());
            Hesapla();
        } 
I have added , but did not
```

Comment: ı solved thanks. I use gridview1.Refreshdata. best ragards